# Не отправляются данные с клиента (андроид) на сервер (java pc)

Tags: java, android, сокет, клиент-сервер

Доброе утро.

Есть клиент на андроиде, с него должна отправиться строка на сервер.
Запускаю клиент на реальном устройстве.

Вот код клиента:

```
public class Client extends Thread {

private boolean running = false;
private static Socket s = null;
private String ip = "тут мой ip";
private int port = 80;
private String data;
static DataInputStream din = null;
static DataOutputStream dout = null;

public Client(String name, int score){
    data = name + " " + score;
}

public void setRunning(boolean b){running = b;}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            s = new Socket(ip, port);
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout.writeUTF(data);
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}
```

}

Все это действо должно отработать в другом классе, вот в этом методе:

```
private void sendData(String name, int score){
    client = new Client(name, score);
    client.setRunning(true);
    client.start();
}
```

Код сервера:

```
public class Server {


static ServerSocket ss;
static Socket s;
static DataInputStream din;
static DataOutputStream dout;

static String data = "";

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        System.out.println("Сервер запущен\n");
        ss = new ServerSocket(80);
        s = ss.accept();

        din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        while(true){
            data = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Score: " + data);
        }

    } catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    System.out.println("Сервер остановлен");
}
```

}

Wi-fi на устройстве включил, ip точно мой, все по-идее должно работать.
Клиент в отдельном потоке, не понимаю тогда в чем дело.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: 80 порт лучше не использовать. Попробуйте с номером порта выше 1024

Comment: И зачем Вы постоянно в цикле подключаетесь к серверу? А затем не закрываете соединение. То есть получается как только Вы запускаете поток он зацикливается. При этом он коннектится к серверу. И ничего не передаёт. Так как data == null

Comment: Хорошо, цикл уберу, только как вы поняли, что data == null, я же перед запуском потока инициализировал data в конструкторе

Comment: Теперь порт 1234, только ничего не изменилось, по-прежнему на сервер ничего не приходит

Comment: В первую очередь, не смотря на ваш код, рекомендую проверить доступ к порту с локальной сети, а потом уже и с устройства, предварительно запустив ваш сервер конечно, если все окей, то смотреть код.

Comment: @Crok разрешения прописаны на сеть?

Comment: Попробовал с локальной сетью - ничего не приходит на сервер.

Comment: разрешение на сеть есть

Comment: @Crok работает мой вариант?

Comment: увы, нет. Даже не представляю, почему не работает.

Answer (score 1):

На стороне клиента:

Client.java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client extends Thread {
    //Все null,false,0 по умолчанию. Можно не писать.
    private boolean running;
    private Socket s;
    private String ip = "192.168.1.4";
    private int port = 1234;
    static DataInputStream din;
    static DataOutputStream dout;

    public void setRunning(boolean b){running = b;}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            s = new Socket(ip, port);
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            while (running);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return s!=null&&s.isConnected();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if(dout!=null&&running) {
            try {
                dout.writeUTF(message);
                dout.flush();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        if(din!=null) try{din.close();}catch(IOException io){}
        if(dout!=null) try{dout.close();}catch(IOException io){}
        if(s!=null) try{s.close();}catch(IOException io){}
    }
}
```

Вызов класса:

```
Client clt = new Client();
clt.setRunning(true);
clt.start();
while(!clt.isConnected());
clt.sendMessage("Hello");
clt.sendMessage(", World!");
clt.close();
```

Манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

На стороне сервера:

Server.java:

```
static ServerSocket ss;
static Socket s;
static DataInputStream din;
static DataOutputStream dout;

static String data = "";

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        System.out.println("Сервер запущен\n");
        ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
        s = ss.accept();

        din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        while((data = din.readUTF())!=null){
            System.out.println("Score: " + data);
        }

    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(dout!=null) try{dout.close();}catch(IOException io){}
        if(din!=null) try{din.close();}catch(IOException io){}
        if(s!=null) try{s.close();}catch(IOException io){}
        if(ss!=null) try{ss.close();} catch(IOException io){}
    }
    System.out.println("Сервер остановлен");
}
```

Comment: Вместо вашего ip написал 127.0.0.1, запустил сервер, запустил приложение на эмуляторе - ничего не пришло.

Comment: Странно у меня через модем работает. У эмуляторов есть проблема с сетью. Я когда свой чат в игре тестил убедился, что он не всегда работает. А на реальном устройстве прибывали?

Comment: и на реальном пробовал, вбивал свой ip - ничего не вышло

Comment: Думаю, проблема в том, что порт, по которому я пытаюсь связать сервер и клиент, закрыт. Вопрос теперь в другом, можно ли в коде открыть порт?

Comment: Можно. Вопрос может и глупый, но Вы точно на тот IP коннектитесь? Через ipconfig узнаете ip или через 2ip.ru? Пробросить можно. У меня даже код где-то валяется. Какая ОС на ПК? У меня как-то на линуксе не работал изначально сервер.

Comment: ip узнаю через 2ip, ОС win7

Comment: @Crock, через 2ip не будет работать. Так как роутер не прокидывает порты. Попробуйте через ipconfig в консоли.

Comment: Такой чат будет работать только с "серыми" ip, то есть теми, что раздаёт Ваш роутер. А для белых надо подрубать UPnP.

Comment: Нет, ничего не выходит. Но, все же спасибо большое Вам за то, что несколько дней помогали и подсказывали мне.

Comment: Не за что. Да мне самому было это интересно недавно. Но я один делал поэтому долго. По-прежнему не отправляют данные? Странно. У меня работает этот код.